# Text between two Views

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve the following result:

- **TV: TextView**
- **IV: ImageView**

[image: Relative layout]

All four views are populated from the database, so have dynamic width (except IV).

ID's from left to right:

```
icon
tv_top
tv_bottom
tv_right
```

I did this Relative Layout taken from this tutorial ([Vogella Android ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                 android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_item_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_item_size"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="21.5sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"

            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"

            >
    </TextView>
```

My problem is that I want to dynamically change the width of my tv_top according to tv_right's width. If tv_right is getting larger I want to make my tv_top's width smaller.

Currently I do this my the  `android:layout_marginRight="70dp"` command which sets a fixed size to my view.

I tried also (in my Adapter - programmatically) things like :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int relativeUsageWidth = viewHolder.tvAppRelativeUsage.getWidth(); // width is always 0
llp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
llp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.icon);
llp.setMargins(0, 0, relativeUsageWidth, 0);
```

Is there any better way to do it than programmatically(maybe xml way)? Should I use Linear Layouts? Which is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TextViews in the middle, don't use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` with an additional margin, but set them to be right of the left ImageView and left of the right TextView and set the width to `match_parent`. This will make them fit directly in between the two other Views.

Example for the two TextViews:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        >
</TextView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:textSize="21.5sp"
        android:singleLine="true">
</TextView>
```

And add a small margin to both views again, so that they don't stick directly on the other Views.

Comment: I was trying this but I also had alignParentRight="true". I think this is simpler solution.

Comment: Yup, but alignParentRight="true" will cause the Vies to end at the right of the parent, while android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_right" will cause them to end at the left side of tv_right, which is more fitting for what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <!-- weight 3 of 4 = 3/4 of available width for this LinearLayout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_bottom"
            android:text="Top line"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Bottom line"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- weight 1 of 4 = 1/4 of available width for this TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Right text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You mean tv_top and tv_bottom in the LinearLayout? I have edited my question so that I clear out which ID belong to wich image.

Comment: @AndreasLympouras, I removed most of your details to make things easier to follow. I've updated my answer as I did have the IDs mixed up. I also used a `RelativeLayout` for the two middle `TextViews` to show a possible way to display those in the way I think you want them.

Comment: I'll leave putting your desired dimensions back in an an exercise for you - I purposefully made the answer more generic for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I believe `layout_toLeftOf` and `layout_toRightOf` is simpler solution.

Comment: @AndreasLympouras Of course, your call. It really depends on how you want to define the size scaling. This will scale the `middle TextView` and `right TextView` widths evenly/proportionally across all screen sizes whereas the root `RelativeLayout` option will resize with the content of the `middle TextViews` and leave the `right TextView` at its `wrap_content` (or specific defined) width. Mark whichever fits your use case, I'll leave this here as an alternative option for future people with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved w/o using any additional layout. All we need is just a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_left"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#888"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_right"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_top"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can set the padding and margin according to your wish.

**[EDIT]** oops didn't noticed the right one was an TextView... Code updated..

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes! this is the solution but 'tknell' gave it first. Thanks anyway.

Comment: *TextView not EditText